# Laravel seeding with relationship Eloquent\Builder failing

Tags: laravel, eloquent, seed, seeding

I'm trying to seed my database with like this:

```
factory(App\User::class, 1)
    ->create()
    ->each(function($u) {
        $role = factory(App\Role::class)->create();
        $u->role()->save( $role );
    });
```

and these are my model factories:

```
$factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => 'Jakub Kohout',
        'email' => 'test@gmail.com',
        'password' => bcrypt('Uchiha'),
        'role_id' => 1
    ];
});

$factory->define(App\Role::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'role_name' => 'Admin',
    ];
});
```

But I got this error:

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$orders
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think the error is being generated because of the code you've posted. Do you get a stack trace with the error?

Comment: it's sure because of this, because when I delete the factory for App::user everything works fine.

Comment: Correlation != causation. This type of error usually pops up when you are attempting to access a property of an `Eloquent Model` on an `Eloquent Builder` object.

Answer (score 4):

Sadly, the each function does not work with single elements. You have to create more than one Model to use the each function:

```
factory(App\User::class, 2)->create()->each(function($u) {
    $role = factory(App\Role::class)->create();

    $u->role()->save( $role );
});
```

[Source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/dca2d68e1d3f21ff1d119eb442cfb8239fed92f1/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/FactoryBuilder.php#L105)

When only one element is created, the instance is returned directly instead of a collection.

This should work for your case:

```
$user = factory(App\User::class)->create();

$role = factory(App\Role::class)->create();

$user->role()->save( $role );
```